# Call startActivityForResult from static method

Tags: android

I have a buttonlistener, and when the user clicks the button I want to start a camera intent. 
At the moment I have this:

```
public class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener 
{
private ArrayList<String> connectedItems;
private String identifier = null;
private Context context;
private EnteredValues enteredValues;

public ButtonListener(Context c, String identifier, ArrayList<String> connectedItems) {
    this.connectedItems = connectedItems;
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.context = c;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (identifier.equals(ButtonItem.takePhoto)) {
        MainActivity.takePhoto();
    }

}
```

Now I want to call a method in my mainActivity and there I want to start startActivityForResult, but I get an error that I can't call startActivityForResult from a static method.

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity{
...
   public static void takePhoto(){
       startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE));
          break;

       //Here I get the error..
   }
```

}

What is the best practice to fix this sort of problem?  pass a mainActivity object to my buttonListener or are there other options?

Many thx :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do not use Application context - as it will break your ActivityStack.
I would recommend to add Activity parameter to this static method:

```
public static void takePhoto(Activity activity, int requestCode){
   activity.startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), requestCode);
}
```

Than just pass Activity from your listener. You'll have to pass Activity instance to it, instead of simple Context, as only Activity can make `startActivityForResult()` calls.

So clickListener code will change as follows: 
    public class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener 
    {
    private ArrayList connectedItems;
    private String identifier = null;
    private Activity activity;
    private EnteredValues enteredValues;

```
public ButtonListener(Activity activity, String identifier, ArrayList<String> connectedItems) {
    this.connectedItems = connectedItems;
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (identifier.equals(ButtonItem.takePhoto)) {
        MainActivity.takePhoto(activity, 100);
    }
}
```

That is a good practice to make such static helpers to avoid creating intents and startActivities from different parts of your code.

Good luck.

Comment: When I do this I get "The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type Context", how can I fix that? :)

Comment: You are right! From Context itself you can only startActivity(), not ForResult(). I'll edit the answer now

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the MainActivity as context to the static method with `this` (or `MainActivity.this`) and then cast it to `Activity`. This will not break your ActivityStack.

In your case create the click listener in MainActivity with:

```
new ButtonListener(this, "abc", null)
new ButtonListener(MainActivity.this, "abc", null) // in a nested class or constructor
```

then in ButtonListener pass the context:

```
MainActivity.takePhoto(context);
```

and finally in MainActivity:

```
public static void takePhoto(Context context){
   ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), 123);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The context in your button listener is very likely to be your activity or something belonging to your activity. Try to start your next activity from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use **[application context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)**

```
getApplicationContext()
```